# How do I make node respond with error if payload is empty

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, jsx

I need a code to respond with error if payload is empty. How do I do this?

```
if(req.body !== {}){
      res.json(newUser)
    }else{
      res.status(400).json('fill in the necessary information')
    }
```

Comment: Whats wrong with your check ? Is it coming in as undefined or an empty object `{}` ?

Comment: also after you set the status, you need to `res.send("whatever")`

Answer (score 1):

The check `req.body !== {}` will ALWAYS be true, since you can't compare objects. You could check if it's undefined, and then check for keys to know if it's empty. Something like this:

```
if(req.body && Object.keys(req.body).length !== 0){
  res.json(newUser)
} else {
  res.status(400).json('fill in the necessary information')
}
```

Read more about object's equality [here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/object-equality-in-javascript.html).

Comment: Not sure why the question had -3 and this answer had zero.
Saved my behind, thanks! Make sure you specify req.body, not req, like I did at first.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(req.body){
  res.json(newUser)
}else{
  res.status(400).json('fill in the necessary information')
}
```